# Assign variable from SSH server to local machine variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh

I have two scripts that are being run.  One runs from a client workstation and calls a script on a server.  I need a variable from the server script and I figured I could do it this way, but it isn't working:

```
#!/bin/sh

local_var=""

ssh user@server " $local_var=\$server_var "

echo "$local_var"
```

My output of local_var is null.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
local_var=$(ssh user@server "echo ${server_var}")
```

Comment: I'm still testing this, but I think it may be the solution

Comment: I'm having no luck with this.  I tried typing it exactly the way you have it, but my variable still comes up null.  I also tried adding a space like this: local_var=$( ssh user@server "echo ${server_var}" )

Comment: Are you sure that `server_var` is set on the remote system?

Comment: yes sir, it's used heavily throughout the server script (which works)

Answer (score 2):

yes, you need to print the variable names and values, then source the output of that. An example:

```
$ source <(ssh user@server 'echo foo=\"$bar\"')
$ echo $foo
bar
```

This works on bash, it may not work on shells which does not support redirecting command output to `source`. For those shells, you may need to create a temporary file first.

Comment: Getting an error on this... "syntax error near unexpected token `(' ..."

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make 3 assumptions:

1. The remote machine is a Linux box.
2. You know the process ID of the remote script's instance.
3. The variable you want is in the remote process's environment.

Assuming the above, the following should work:

```
local_var=$( ssh user@server bash -c '
   while IFS="=" read -d '' -r name value; do
     [[ $name = "server_var" ]] && echo $server_var && break
   done' < /proc/$REMOTE_SCRIPT_PROC_ID/environ )
```