# How to set local variable to value of variable on an ssh server

Tags: linux, shell, unix

My other question here [Assign variable from SSH server to local machine variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588872/assign-variable-from-ssh-server-to-local-machine-variable/16589109#16589109) was never successfully answered, and I'm not sure how to "bump" the question to get more views, but how can I set the value of my local variable to the value of a variable on an ssh server?

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh_cmd="ssh-t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-$$ -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=10"

local_var=""

$ssh_cmd user@server " server_var=\"test\" "

local_var=$($ssh_cmd user@server 'echo $server_var')

echo $local_var
```

This will result in a null.

**EDIT**

I'm using ssh connection sharing and I thought that the entire session (along with the connection was shared), thus I was establishing an initial connection and setting the variable, and reconnecting to that session to echo out the variable that was set.

I have a program on an ssh server that retrieves the IP address of a virtual machine.  My local script needs this address so that I run something against the virtual machine from my local script.

The ssh server does much more than just get the IP address, but that one functionality is something I need to know on my local script.

Comment: `local_var=$(ssh user@server "echo \${server_var}")` works for me

Comment: Wow, this definitely is not working for me..

Comment: `local_var=$(ssh user@server 'echo $server_var')` works for me

Comment: Well thanks.. this at least tells me that something else is really wrong

Comment: Did you try `local_var=\`ssh user@server echo ${server_var}\``?

Comment: Don't assign the value. Instead, let the command put it's output to standard output. That will tell you if the ssh successfully echoes the remote value or not. Start further debugging after that.

Comment: @Samveen it returns null as well.  The value is definitely set on the server though.

Comment: How is the variable being set on the server? `ssh user@server "command"` doesn't run .profile, so variables set there won't be seen.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using ssh connection sharing and riding off of the process of an established connection.  So the initial connection simply does a `local_var=\"test\"` and then I run `$ssh_sharing_cmd user@server 'echo $local_var'` it reconnects to that session but the value is null.

Comment: @nkon: Variables are not shared between the two sessions, only the authentication.

Comment: Connection sharing shares the connection and sshd process, but not the shell process.

Comment: I see, so that variable is unknown with subsequent connection attempts?  I assumed the entire session was shared.  Other than setting a perm variable, is there a way around this?

Comment: Variables are set in processes, not on the server per se. We'll need to know more about what you are trying to do (including how and where the desired variable is set) to provide a useful solution.

Comment: @chepner will do, I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typically impossible (ignoring debugger tricks) to find out the value of a variable in the address space of a running process without that process explicitly sharing it. It can write the value to disk, and you can read that file from another process (either run locally, or via `ssh`).

Comment: To add to this answer, you can do `ssh u@s "echo 'name=value' >/some/safe/place ; source /some/safe/place"` and then `ssh u@s "source /some/safe/place; echo \$name"`

Comment: @chepner I see what you mean (I think). So this variable is still set even when I establish a new session, albeit now in an inaccessbile address space, so since it's a new session an echo to this variable will result in null since I'm trying to echo a value from a different shell?

Comment: Right. Each `ssh` session starts a new process on the remote server, even if a single `ssh` process is managing all the connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example, `local_var=$(ssh user@server "echo \${server_var}")`, works for me.  Are you sure the variable you're trying to read is set when you call ssh like this?  Remember when you pass a command to `ssh`, it creates a non-interactive shell, which results in different shell initialization (and often fewer variables being set).